# When is the proper time to setRequestedOrientation between fragments in Android?

Tags: android, fragment, orientation, landscape, portrait

I want to know when is the proper time and what is the proper way (best practice) to setRequestedOrientation() between fragment transactions.
Lets say that I am on my menu which is in PORTRAIT then I open a new fragment that is in LANDSCAPE, should I setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) in the "onCreate()" of the opened fragment or should I set it in a OnBackStackChangedListener() that is in my Activity?

If neither of the past two were the best practice let me know.
Thanks.